# reference variable array

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I always use `$text = $datasql[0];`
where `$datasql = array('0'=>array('some'=>'text', 'some2'=>'text2'), '1'=>$data, etc...);`

and found work construction `$datasql = &$datasql[0];` and work, why?

That really reference?? and how remember php in memory this solution.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I interpreted it as: how can `$datasql = & $datasql[0]` work, if the original variable is no longer there to be referenced.

Answer (score 3):

Every variable is a reference to a value. Normally the value is copied when you use it, but with `&` the *reference* is copied.

Suppose you have the following variable:

```
$original = 'john';
```

If you *assign* the value from $datasql to a variable, that value is copied:

```
$text = $original;
```

If you assign a *reference*, the value is not copied but referenced:

```
$text = & $original;
```

This means that `$text` points to the value of `$original`. Now, if you unset `$original`, the contents of `$text` are still valid:

```
unset($original);
echo $text; // john
```

This is because PHP knows there is still a reference to the value of `$original`, so it deletes the `$original` variable as name, but not the contents.

Your example is similar, except that the variable is not explicitly unset, but overwritten. It is a reference to a value, just like any other variable.